# pthread_create issue

Tags: c++, gcc, pthreads

I have this code:

```
void* ConfigurationHandler::sendThreadFunction(void* callbackData)
{
   const EventData* eventData = (const EventData*)(callbackData);

   //Do Something

   return NULL;
}

void ConfigurationHandler::sendCancel()
{
    EventData* eventData = new EventData();
    eventData ->Name = "BLABLA"

    pthread_t threadId = 0;
    int ret = pthread_create(&threadId,
                             NULL,                                                              
                             ConfigurationHandler::sendThreadFunction,
                             (void*) eventData );                                   // args passed to thread function
    if (ret)
    {
        log("Failed to launch thread!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        ret = pthread_detach(threadId);
    }   
}
```

I am getting a compiler error:

```
error: argument of type 'void* (ConfigurationHandler::)(void*)' does not match 'void* (*)(void*)'
```

Comment: You can't safely pass a C++ method - even a static method - as a routine to `pthread_create`.

Comment: What's the better way? how can I achieve this above funtionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical approach to your problem is to pass C++ object to pthread_create() via void pointer (this data pointer in its interface). The thread function passed will be global (possible static function) which knows that the void pointer is actually an C++ object.

Like in this example:

```
void ConfigurationHandler::sendThreadFunction(EventData& eventData)
{
   //Do Something
}

// added code to communicate with C interface
struct EvendDataAndObject {
   EventData eventData;
   ConfigurationHandler* handler;
};
void* sendThreadFunctionWrapper(void* callbackData)
{
   EvendDataAndObject* realData = (EvendDataAndObject*)(callbackData);

   //Do Something
   realData->handler->sendThreadFunction(realData->eventData);
   delete realData;
   return NULL;
}

void ConfigurationHandler::sendCancel()
{
    EvendDataAndObject* data = new EvendDataAndObject();
    data->eventData.Name = "BLABLA";
    data->handler = this; // !!!

    pthread_t threadId = 0;
    int ret = pthread_create(&threadId,
                             NULL,                                                              
                             sendThreadFunctionWrapper,
                             data ); 
    if (ret)
    {
        log("Failed to launch thread!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        ret = pthread_detach(threadId);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't safely pass a C++ method - even a static method - as a routine to `pthread_create`.

Assuming you don't pass an object - i.e., `ConfigurationHandler::sendThreadFunction` is declared as a static method:

```
// the following fn has 'C' linkage:

extern "C" {

void *ConfigurationHandler__fn (void *arg)
{
    return ConfigurationHandler::sendThreadFunction(arg); // invoke C++ method.
}

}
```

And `ConfigurationHandler__fn` would be passed as the argument to `pthread_create`.

Comment: Why can't you safely pass a C++ static method or function?

Comment: @slavik262: because C and C++ calling conventions can be different. Calling a C++ function which is not declared extern "C" from C is also not safe.